# How to find the 8-bit two’s complement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I find the the $8-bit$ two’s complement for the integer $115_{10}$?

($10$ is the small number to the right of $115$. Sorry, don't know how to write it using keyboard?)

Comment: What is $115$ sub $10$? Is it $115 - 10 = 105$?

Comment: 10 is the small number to the right of 115. Sorry, don't know how to write it using keyboard?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to express $115_{10}$ $(115$ "base 10"$ in two's complement notation (assuming 8 bits)?

Comment: Ah, $115$ in base $10$, $0x73$, $01110011$. Do you want the bit pattern of $-115$ in $8$-bit two's complement?

Comment: amWhy - Yes. How is that done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply find the base two representation and add a leading zero $$115_{10} = 1110011 = 01110011$$ The number in base two uses 7 bits, so we need to add a leading zero to use all eight bits, and the leading zero then conveys that the number is positive.

Do you know how to express $-115_{10}$? Flip zeros for ones in the 8-bit representation of $115_{10},$ and vice versa, then add 1 bit:

$$-115_{10} = 10001100 + 00000001 = 10001101$$

Note that this process of reversing 1's and 0's guarantees the the leading bit is equal to $1$, which conveys that the decimal number represented is negative.

Comment: Great answer and interesting about how to express negative.  Thank you!!

Comment: Is "finding the twos complement" synonymous with making something binary, then? I am unclear on the difference.

Comment: Not quite: the 7 bit representation 1110011 is in binary, but not two's complement. The complement of that number in two's complement is the negative of 115, but in binary, something else altogether. It allows us to express positive and negative values, where strictly binary representations typically used only when all numbers in question are non-negative integers.

Comment: I see now.  Clear.  Thanks.

Comment: @amWhy: All right, getting into some digital logic! :-) +1

Comment: I like digital logic...I discovered "modern programming" (machine language/digital) and high level languages a bit late compared to other fields, and loved/love it! (Actually, there's very little I've studied that I haven't loved. I want to learn it all!) ;-)

Comment: Can you explain why this algorithm works?

Answer (score 0):

Convert 115 into binary and make sure you use all 8 bits. if you wanted it to be negative then  flip all the bits and add one to get -115

Comment: OK so for turning 115 to binary I got 1110011.  Is that correct?  What else needs to be done?